# Errors while starting Nginx server after the successfull compilation of Lua modules

Tags: nginx, lua

I have compiled my Nginx package using lua module. Though the compilation was successful but I am getting the below error while starting the nginx server :

```
nginx: [warn] lua_load_resty_core is deprecated (the lua-resty-core library is required since ngx_lua v0.10.16) in /app/middleware/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:24
nginx: [alert] detected a LuaJIT version which is not OpenResty's; many optimizations will be disabled 
and performance will be compromised (see https://github.com/openresty/luajit2 for OpenResty's LuaJIT or, even better, 
consider using the OpenResty releases from https://openresty.org/en/download.html)
nginx: [alert] failed to load the 'resty.core' module (https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core); 
ensure you are using an OpenResty release from https://openresty.org/en/download.html (reason: /app/middleware/lua-resty-core/lib/lua/resty/core.lua:6: 
loop or previous error loading module 'resty.core.var') in /app/middleware/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:704
```

solution from google for above error:

Currently My nginx version is 1.20.2 .Kindly assist since we have a requirement to log response body in nginx access.log .

Regards,
Raghu

Comment: Did you read these messages? They explain pretty thoroughly what needs to be done.

Comment: I have read the messages thoroughly  and didn't find a  solution to fix the error. Hence I have posted in this forum.